# Insercción de datos en PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Realizo un proyecto de un sistema de nómina lo cuál necesito que al insertar los registros en mi Base de Datos tome los ID de las tablas lo cual son llaves foráneas de otras tablas y en mi base de datos quede reflejado por ID pero en mi interfaz lo tome como la descripción.

Mi problema es el siguiente en mi BD tengo la tabla "trabajador" que es donde tengo las llaves foráneas (ademas que es la principal tabla)  de las siguientes tablas  "puesto","empresa" y "ctg_turno" . En mi código lo que necesito hacer es que tome esas llaves foráneas (ID) y las inserte en mi BD pero para el usuario que se muestre en la lista desplegable lo que tengo almacenado en las tablas de mis  llaves foráneas pero la descripción de esas tablas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
if (@!$_SESSION['user']) {
 header("Location:index.php");
}elseif ($_SESSION['rol']==2) {
 header("Location:index2.php");
}
?>
<html lang="en">
  

  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gesti&oacuten de Nómina</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    

    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
  </head>
<body data-offset="40" background="images/fondotot.jpg" style="background-attachment: fixed">

<div id="page">
   <div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"></a>
    Sistema Integral de Nómina
   </div><br> </br>
   


<div class="container">
<header class="header">
<div class="row">
 <?php
 include("include/cabecera.php");
 ?>
</div>
</header>

  <!-- Navbar
    ================================================== -->

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
 <div class="container">
   <div class="nav-collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
   <li class=""><a href="index2.php">BIENVENIDO</a></li>
    
 
  </ul>
  <form action="#" class="navbar-search form-inline" style="margin-top:6px">
  
  </form>
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li><a href="">Bienvenido <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?></strong> </a></li>
     <li><a href="desconectar.php"> Cerrar Sesión </a></li>    
  </ul>
   </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
 </div>
  </div><!-- /navbar-inner -->
</div>

<br />

    
             <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<strong>Impresi&oacute;n de Reporte</strong>
             <a href="app/reportes/reporte_trabajador.php" target="_blank"><img src="images/printer.png"  width="50" height="50" 



<!-- ======================================================================================================================== -->
<div class="row">
 
 
  
 <div class="span12">

  <div class="caption">
  
<!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////Empieza cuerpo del documento interno////////////////////////////////////////////-->
  <center><h2> Administración de Trabajadores Registrados</h2></center>
  <div class="well well-small">
  <hr class="soft"/>
  <center><h4>Trabajadores Registrados</h4></center>
  <div class="row-fluid">
  



   <?php

    require("connect_db.php");
    $sql=("SELECT * FROM trabajador");
 
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

    echo "<table border='1'; class='table table-hover';>";
     echo "<tr class='warning'>";
        echo "<td>No. de Control</td>";
      echo "<td>Nombre</td>";
      echo "<td>Apellido Paterno</td>";
      echo "<td>Apellido Materno</td>";
      echo "<td>NSS</td>";
      echo "<td>CURP</td>";
      echo "<td>RFC</td>";
      echo "<td>Puesto</td>";
      echo "<td>Area</td>";
      echo "<td>Turno</td>";
      echo "<td>Empresa</td>";
      echo "<td>Editar</td>";
      
     echo "</tr>";

       
   ?>
     
   <?php 
     while($arreglo=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       echo "<tr class='success'>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[0]</td>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[1]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[2]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[3]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[4]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[5]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[6]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[7]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[8]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[9]</td>";
      echo "<td>$arreglo[10]</td>";
         

         echo "<td><a href='actualizar_trabajador.php?id_control=$arreglo[0]'><img src='images/actualizar.gif' class='img-rounded'></td>";
      
      

      
     echo "</tr>";
    }


   ?>
   
      
          
     
  
  
  <div class="span8">
  
  </div> 
  </div> 
  <br/>
  


  <!--EMPIEZA DESLIZABLE-->
  
   <!--TERMINA DESLIZABLE-->



  
  
  </div>

  


  

<!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////Termina cuerpo del documento interno////////////////////////////////////////////-->
</div>

 </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer
      ================================================== -->


</div><!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </style>
 
 <?php
     include("includes/menus.php"); ?>
     </div>
     <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <!--<script src="includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  <!-- Add in any FooTable dependencies we may need -->
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Add in FooTable itself -->
  <script src="js/compiled/footable.js"></script>
  <!-- Initialize FooTable -->
  <script>
   jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
   });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Buenas noches Alvaro, mi problema es el siguiente en mi BD tengo la tabla "trabajador" que es donde tengo las llaves foráneas (ademas que es la principal tabla)  de las siguientes tablas  "puesto","empresa" y "ctg_turno" . En mi código lo que necesito hacer es que tome esas llaves foráneas (ID) y las inserte en mi BD pero para el usuario que se muestre en la lista desplegable lo que tengo almacenado en las tablas de mis  llaves foráneas pero la descripción de esas tablas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es cómo estás generando las `select`. Recuerda que **aunque se muestre un texto en la opción, el valor puede ser diferente.**

Ahora mismo estás generando las opciones teniendo un mismo valor y texto: la descripción. Por ejemplo, así lo haces para el puesto:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_puesto, descripcion_puesto FROM puesto";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[descripcion_puesto]\">$row[descripcion_puesto] </option>";   

}
```

Pero quieres que cuando se inserte en la tabla `trabajador` lo que se guarde es el `id` para que sirva como clave foránea. Entonces lo único que tendrías que hacer es cambiar el `value` del `option` para que sea el `id` en lugar de la descripción. Por ejemplo, con el código de antes del puesto:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_puesto, descripcion_puesto FROM puesto";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_puesto]\">$row[descripcion_puesto] </option>";   

}
```

De ese modo, cuando se envíe el formulario, el valor pasado será el id y no la descripción. Sólo te quedaría hacer ese mismo cambio para "area", "empresa", "ctg_turno" o las tablas que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro, Saludos.

Comment: Estimado Alvaro. Ahora mi problema es el modulo de consultas ya me aparece efectivamente lo que tengo en mi BD en la tabla de trabajador relacionadas con mis llaves foraneas de las otras tablas. Lo que necesito es que de igual forma en la interfaz aparezca la descripcion mas no el ID.